# Is It Okay to use helpers in views?

Tags: url, kohana, helper

Simple question about best-practice. I'm using Kohana... is it okay to use helpers in views? For example, to use *URL::site()*. I could pass it from controller, you know. I assume it's okay, because there are helpers like HTML that is meant to be used in views, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're currently doing it is ok, altough the whole practice of having any logics in views is questionable, but it's how Kohana is currently recommending.

When you get to use ViewModel pattern (with Kostache?), you'll separate all logics from templates. Until then, it's ok to use methods that don't do anything that should be done in the controller / model (echo, conditions and loops are "considered allowed").